# How to get data from a tag if it's present in HTML else Empty String if the tag is not present in web scraping Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

[Picture contains HTML code for the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkRKx.png)

case 1:

```
<li> 
    <a> some text: </a><strong> 'identifier:''random words' </strong>
</li>
```

case 2:

```
<li>
    <a> some text: </a>
</li>
```

I want to scrape values for identifiers if it's present, else I want to put an empty string if there is no identifier in that particular case.
I am using scrapy or you can help me with BeautifulSoup as well and will really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit unclear what do you want exactly, because your screenshot is little bit different than your example in your question. I suppose you want to search text `"some text:"` and then get next value inside `<strong>` (or empty string if there isn't any):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''
<li>
    <a> some text: </a><strong> 'identifier:''random words' </strong>
</li>
<li>
    <a> some text: </a>
</li>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

for t in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.contents[0].strip() == 'some text:'):
    identifier = t.parent.find('strong')
    identifier = identifier.get_text(strip=True) if identifier else ''
    print('Found:', identifier)
```

Prints:

```
Found: 'identifier:''random words'
Found:
```

Comment: thanks this worked fine! 'Gratitude ' and is there any way for the same with scrapy ?

Comment: @dashkandhar I don't use scrapy at all, but I can imagine you can combine scrapy and bs4 together.

Comment: yes! that's what I am now trying, thank you so much for your prompt reply!